# How to calculate velocity of target after Oblique collision

Tags: homework-and-exercises, collision, free-body-diagram

This is kind of simple problem and I am sure many would be able to solve it quickly. I have some assumptions about it but would like to validate.

So the problem as show in image below. Lets say I have a triangular object with a smooth one side. A ball coming at velocity **u** collide at the center of the surface at an angle of 45 degrees. I want to calculate the velocity at which the triangle will be pushed back and also the ball rebounds.

I know the rebound will create 90 degree angle. Also there is somewhere **u*cos(theta)** not sure where. I would like to calculate the final **V** of ball and **V'** the triangle. I a also thinking the direction of pushed back triangle will be perpendicular to the surface.

Update:
the drawing below is top view, that means ball is not dropping from air rather its sliding horizontally. The triangle is on its back and can move in two dimension. Also for sake of understanding concept please ignore friction forces etc.

[image]

Note: please ignore the rotation of target, after scouring internet I have seen examples of the target rotating. I hardly found anything that made any sense to me so turning to Stackexchange.

Thanks

Comment: Is the triangular object sitting on a surface?

Comment: Apologies, I should have mentioned this. Let me update in question description. the drawing I have is top view, that means ball is not dropping from air but rather its sliding horizontally. Also for sake of understanding concept please ignore friction forces etc.

Comment: What work have you attempted in seeking he solution yourself? Have you tried conservation of momentum in the two directions this problem involves?

Comment: Yes. from my knowledge of head on collision. I tried same principles like "Approach velocity = -Separation velocity". In this case Target triangle is stationary so its 0. Approach velocity is "u". From a ball on a slope problem that normal velocity is uCos(Theta). What I am wondering is whether Triangle's V' is also uCos(Theta) and if it is then what should V be because then V+V' = u. finally what signs V and V' should have. In head on collision objects have +ve and -ve velocities and after collision they reverse their sign. So does that mean V becomes -ve and V' is +ve ?